# How can I replace a Delta 1400 shower valve cartridge?

Tags: plumbing, repair, shower

I have a delta 1400 shower valve that I had to replace. The existing one was full of sediment. When I put everything back together water just comes out the tub spout as if the valve wasn't there. When I look at valve/cartridge there is an ever so small gap between the metal casing in the wall and the cartridge. I assume this is why I am having water come out below, even though I don't quiet understand why it is full pressure. Is there a trick to getting this cartridge back into place? I've pushed it in quiet hard and it won't go any further. [This is what I am working with](http://www.wholesaleplumbing.com/wp-replacement-shower-cartridge-rp19804-for-delta-1300-1400-faucets.html?gclid=CKicpPnK_LQCFexlOgodJwIA2w).

Comment: The "O" rings are not damaged? Are they seated correctly? this could be one of the challanges.

Comment: One of the O rings around the cold water one is damaged. Could that be causing it? I had damaged them once and so I replaced it but the way I am putting it in is breaking it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem. Answering it in hopes that it helps someone else someday... The cartridge I bought in the store was in fact the wrong piece. While the white part that is further away from the wall was the correct type the blue part was model UPG 7 vs UPG 2. It looks almost the same but the intake parts are slightly offset.